# Problem with mapping tag in hibernate configuration file

Tags: hibernate, orm

I am using hibernate annotations and when I do following everything works fine

```
sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration()
                                .addPackage("istreamcloudframework.objectmodel.member")
                                .addAnnotatedClass(User.class)
     .buildSessionFactory();
```

but I wanted to avoid specifying all the classes in this manner so I tried taking that into hibernate config file in following manner,

```
    mapping package="istreamcloudframework.objectmodel.member"
    mapping class="istreamcloudframework.objectmodel.member.User"
```

I get following error,

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: istreamcloudframework.objectmodel.member.User
```

Whats going wrong over here?

*P.S: I have checked all the annotation imports and its not org.hibernate.annotations.Entity. I am using javax.persistence.* imports;
*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `AnnotationConfiguration` instance to process XML file containing your configuration, but you should be able to specify your classes there. See [Hibernate Annotations documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/ch01.html#setup-configuration) for more details.

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <mapping package="istreamcloudframework.objectmodel.member" />
    <mapping class="istreamcloudframework.objectmodel.member.User" />
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Creating session factory:

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration()
 .configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

Also note that it's not necessary to map package (doing so won't map classes in said package)  unless you have package-level annotations.

Comment: hmmm....netbeans's clean & build made it work. I am curious why netbeans behaves like this, thanks anyway...